# setTitleTextAttributes doesn't work for UITabBarItem when it is unselected in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I am trying to custom my `UITabBarController`. I have it embedded in my `UIViewController`, I also created a class for this `UITabBarController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //custom tab bar
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 153.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 171.0/255.0, green: 203.0/255.0, blue: 61.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    self.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    self.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Disabled)

    for item in self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
    {
        item.image = item.selectedImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

`setTitleTextAttributes` doesn't have any effects on the tab bar item. Can somebody please help me to find where the error is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the code that works in this case to put still in the UITabBarController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

//custom tab bar
self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 102.0/255.0, blue: 153.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 171.0/255.0, green: 203.0/255.0, blue: 61.0/255.0, alpha: 1)

for item in self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
{
    item.image = item.selectedImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:UIControlState.Disabled)
    item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 171.0/255.0, green: 203.0/255.0, blue: 61.0/255.0, alpha: 1)], forState:UIControlState.Selected)
}
}
```

Comment: For me that tint colour of barTintColor and  tintColor, did all the magic for normal. thank

Answer (score 0):

The tab bar items belong to the individual child view controllers, so you need to change the attributes in those controllers, not the tab bar controller.

Comment: I tried to change the attributes  in controllers in the viewdidload, when the 1° view is load, the tab bar item of the 2° is still ios default color which is grey, only if I click on the 2° view its tab bar item is set with the right color. Can you please explain in more detail where I have to put the codes?

Comment: @Chongzl, put the code in awakeFromNib instead. viewDidLoad is not called on any controllers other than the first one, until you click on their tab.